# Trying to dispatch action from Vuex module doesn't work. [vuex] unknown action type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm trying to register a `Vuex` module without success. Here's my code:

stores/index.js:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import resourcesModule from './resources';

import axios from '@/helpers/axiosInterceptor';

Vue.use(Vuex);


export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    resources: resourcesModule
  },
  state: {...}})
```

stores/resources/index.js

```
export default {
    state: {
        resources: []
    },
    actions: {
        fetchResources(store) {
            const request = axios.get('/api/musical_resources');
            request.then((res) => {
                store.commit('setResources', res.data);;
            }); 
            return request;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setResources(state, payload) {
            state.resources = payload;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        resources({resources}) {
            return resources;
        }
    }
};
```

I'm trying to dispatch the `fetchResources` action from another component and that gives me " [vuex] unknown action type: fetchResources"

When I inspect the store object, in _modules property there is only the `root` property, so I suspect maybe I'm missing something when registering the module.

When I `console.log(resourcesModules);` in `stores/index.js` file everything looks fine.

So, what's my problem? Thank you very much

EDIT:

Also tryied this in stores/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import axios from '@/helpers/axiosInterceptor';

Vue.use(Vuex);


export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    resources: {
      state() {
        return {
          resources: []
        }
      },
      actions: {
        fetchResources(store) {
          const request = axios.get('/api/musical_resources');
          request.then((res) => {
            store.commit('setResources', res.data);;
          });
          return request;
        }
      },
      mutations: {
        setResources(state, payload) {
          state.resources = payload;
        }
      },
      getters: {
        resources({ resources }) {
          return resources;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  state: {...}})
```

Without success

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    resourcesModule
  },
  state: {...}})
```

to dispatch `fetchResources`

or

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    resources: resourcesModule
  },
  state: {...}})
```

to dispatch `resources.fetchResources`

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! So, how this behavior differs from "namespaced: true". It's a little confusing! Thanks you again!

Comment: Sorry! I was actually testing it without removing "fetchResources" from the root store. Still not working :(

Comment: You sure? It should be working, it works in lot's of my projects

Comment: Yes, I don't know why isn't working. Is it helpfull to you take a look into my repo? This is it https://github.com/damianciancio/gestion-orquestas

Comment: Hey mate, I looked at your repo  and you have `import musicalResources from './resources';` but your `modules` is empty, just put your imported module inside `modules: {
    musicalResources
  },`

Comment: Yes, I removed it from there because it wasn't working. I will put it there again as soon as possible and tell you what happens! Thank you very much for looking at the repo

Comment: You are welcome mate, if you want you can look at one ofy my repos to see [another way of structuring vuex modules](https://github.com/nijepa/studio88_frontend/tree/master/src/store), cheers :)